# how to fix a document.body is null-error

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, width

I'm having a document.body is null error in my javascript because I use:

```
$(window).width()
```

as value to assign to a variable in my

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

I would be very grateful to anyone who could help me with this.

Kind regards

edit: sorry if this all was unclear. I have a demo at: http://www.wpmonk.com/demo/hypowired
at first the theme will load but then becomes white (because of the error) but when you reload you can see the whole theme because then he knows the value for $(window).width()

I'm using this code to center the layout (not possible with css because the left needs to have a width aswell.)

```
function positioneerElement(){      
    $breedte = (document.body.clientWidth - 1124) / 2;
    $('#bg_left').css({
        'width': $breedte
    });
    $('.container').css({
        'margin-left': $breedte
    });
}
```

I call function `positioneerElement()` in the load function.

Sorry if this wasn't clear I though it wasn't necessary to put the demo here for this nor the code.
However I would like to thank the people who are trying to help!

Comment: Please post a minimal test case: enough code to be complete and produce the error, but no more.

Comment: Why dont you people learn to down-vote questions like these?!  Hover over the down-arrow, read the tooltip, and do your damn job.

Comment: @Josh: Probably a bit harsh I think.  I figured we might ask for more information first? Ayrton probably honestly thought that more info wasn't required; hopfully he'll update the question.  But by downvoting, it's less likely that people will try to help and less likely he'll get an answer. I thought the SO community was here to help people, not berate and punish them for miscommunications...

Comment: Come on @Damovisa, you know its all about rep ;)  Up-voted to mend.

Comment: @Justin - Oh man, you're right. Sorry, what was I thinking? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with outis - we need some more code.

That said:

- Are you sure you're doing *all* your work inside the $(document).ready function?
- Do you definitely have a correctly formed (and closed) body tag and valid xhtml?
- Does this happen on all browsers?

One suggestion:

Does the problem persist if you put the `positioneerElement` function in the $(document).ready function as well?  I'm wondering whether the browser evaluates document.body prior to the document loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function positioneerElement(){      
    $breedte = (document.body.clientWidth - 1124) / 2;
    $('#bg_left').css({
        'width': $breedte
    });
    $('.container').css({
        'margin-left': $breedte
    });

    // your other code, including
    positioneerElement();
});
```

Comment: I added some more info,

I'm doing this all in the ready functiones yes, my code should be valid xhtml & this happens in every browser

Comment: thank you very much. Apperantly it all had to do with this. I found it strange because in other projects I didn't need to put the functions in my document.ready.

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you only call `$(window).width()` *after* you have included the `<body>` tag (eg. in the ready callback), and/or use a Standards Mode doctype declaration. You should be doing that anyway: Quirks Mode sucks.

The issue is, to read the viewport size in Quirks Mode jQuery must look at `document.body.clientWidth` instead of `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. If you haven't started your `<body>` yet, there is not `document.body` node present.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include jquery.js, and not jquery.min.js 
It looks like some bug in it
This works for me

Answer (score 1):

Well, just based on the information you have given me it might be that the body has not loaded properly yet. Please see here for more detials: http://www.coderanch.com/t/122834/HTML-JavaScript/document-body-null-or-not#606782

I would say more but I too agree with outis that you need to post some more code for us to debug.